# shell script to capture string from a table

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am writing a shell script to upload a file to a specific folder on google drive. I have started out on the terminal though, to see how it can be done.

```
$ now=$(date +"%Y")
$ echo now
2015
$ drive list | grep -w $now
0B6g6AG_EmqeJM3ZKSHc5cUNJZ2M                                               delete.txt                               18.0 B     2015-06-12 10:32:05   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJVkZZVXI4OWtHVEk                                               delete.txt                               17.0 B     2015-06-11 18:58:19   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJTWIxVVBLSjB3YXc                                               Open Drive Replacements 06_11_2015.xls   9.7 KB     2015-06-11 12:03:13   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJakdNVjhjSTk0V1U                                               Open Drive Replacements 06_08_2015.xls   13.8 KB    2015-06-08 10:06:17   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQ1JldDFOTUt0Uzg                                               Open Drive Replacements 06_05_2015.xls   798.2 KB   2015-06-05 17:03:46   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQW1LaGU4UnJqdHM                                               YYZ Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          84.0 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:43   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQ2R3QkJDWkp1X2c                                               YVR3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         30.2 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:40   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJZjMwOS1oZGRLN2M                                               TYO Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          38.4 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:38   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJelcwYXBkOVpFeTQ                                               TYO3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         108.5 KB   2015-06-05 14:56:35   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJZ2E4eXVPUkNaUmM                                               TLV1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         34.3 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:33   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJUWZESVZGUmc2QWc                                               SYD Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          17.9 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:31   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJaExsQmdwOGFiQUU                                               SNV1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         58.9 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:27   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJVW9YbDdXNzU5SWs                                               SIN Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          22.0 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:24   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJN21zRHhkMzhPNnc                                               SEA3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         92.2 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:22   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJbU81QURvZjVJZUU                                               SEA2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         34.3 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:20   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJOTZIcDlrUy0tTGc                                               PMO1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         22.0 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:18   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQVdXNUwwaE9CRmc                                               PHX2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         9.7 KB     2015-06-05 14:56:15   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJakVLeFhNb2NnSkU                                               PAR3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         186.9 KB   2015-06-05 14:56:12   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJNFhDVUZtRjYtNk0                                               ORD Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          50.7 KB    2015-06-05 14:56:06   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJUUxEUDh6Vm0tMXM                                               ORD4 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         34.3 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:59   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJc3hJalc3R25qa1E                                               ORD2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         26.1 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:56   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJaHhRN1N6NElkd1U                                               MIA1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         88.1 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:54   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJWktoQU5wTU13YTA                                               MEX1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         17.9 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:51   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJb2FEWWwwQXF2SEk                                               MDE1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         9.7 KB     2015-06-05 14:55:48   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJMkxidzNpR1k2alk                                               MAD1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         92.2 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:46   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJY212ZHdJaDJXa3c                                               MAA1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         42.5 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:44   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJUy1Ec0NCN09lVTg                                               LON3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         145.9 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:41   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJV0tOQ1FmUVhtNUE                                               LON2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         54.8 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:37   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQXUwMEpMaHBvOEU                                               LIN1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         116.7 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:35   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJX1ZBNjFvZWkwU0E                                               LCY1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         154.1 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:32   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJODhxbzM4dmk3Mk0                                               LAX6 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         108.5 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:30   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJcTlxcm8zb0tCdDg                                               ICN1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         42.5 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:27   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJZ0x3MVNkTTZOcWs                                               IAD5 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         104.4 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:25   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJc0ZIMzNzN2R6c2c                                               HKG Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          34.3 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:23   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJSzhtbm1VV01QNFU                                               FRF Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          79.9 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:20   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJam1uMXBxQUxodDA                                               FRF3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         178.7 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:18   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJMi1EWlJPazlPcWc                                               EWR1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         178.7 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:15   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJY3Z5TURmdDhaR3M                                               DAL Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          38.4 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:13   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJYmdMclVVWWJYVXM                                               DAL2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         133.6 KB   2015-06-05 14:55:11   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJTXF6TVBCRDl5dWs                                               BAH1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         13.8 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:08   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJRlRONW9JVXlGbmc                                               ATL2 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         38.4 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:06   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJQzVzSDlVWEVYSFU                                               ATL1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         63.0 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:03   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJZmpiY25ROXJqYU0                                               ARN1 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         63.0 KB    2015-06-05 14:55:01   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJMlFDbWp6MDI5X00                                               AMS Replacements 06_05_2015.xls          38.4 KB    2015-06-05 14:54:58   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJbzdkUFdnMlFSUVU                                               AMS3 Replacements 06_05_2015.xls         58.9 KB    2015-06-05 14:54:52   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJfkVwNDE4bkxqY3YtdFhaMWFkNGZhQVZPMV9leFhGbWF1MXY4SVFiNXlMNkU   06_05_2015                               0.0 B      2015-06-05 14:54:28   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJeTBUT00zdGxBeG8                                               2015                                     0.0 B      2015-06-02 10:25:52   
0B79uElAwuDVMfkdvSnJQNEM1Q1VINzZWcDZEWUJGT1o2RXYwTDRuNFVOcGRmbDJPVm81U1E   2014                                     0.0 B      2015-05-09 15:39:31   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJTXllSEM1QzcxMGM                                               unnamed5.gif                             566.0 B    2015-05-26 10:44:20   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJbnpLN1FKVkUxTGM                                               unnamed (2).png                          502.0 B    2015-05-26 10:44:07   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJNlhfaDlQLW9jeE0                                               unnamed.png                              441.0 B    2015-05-26 10:43:48   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJV2dqNHBpc2RpTkk                                               unnamed (1).png                          325.0 B    2015-05-26 10:43:28   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJTUtGcDVmMzhpeVE                                               unnamed.png                              453.0 B    2015-05-26 10:38:20   
0B6g6AG_EmqeJa2hRNkgwY3gxd0E                                               agvuykfd.jpg                             4.7 KB     2015-05-26 10:34:41
```

The first column is the file/folder id, second column is the file/folder name from my google drive.

I need to look for a folder by the name yyyy (current year). And then retrieve its id. If the folder does not exist then I have to create one.

I am currently using the [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

How do I get the desired file id from the above table?

Comment: Seems like the `--query` option mentioned in the gdrive documentation would be a much better way than downloading the entire table and filtering it locally. Let Google search for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me-

```
drive list | grep -w " 2015 " | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+'
```